# What is the numerical complexity of computing the empirical cdf of an array?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

It's all in the title. Suppose $X$ is an array of n floats. The [empirical CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) is the function (of t):

```
Fn(t) = (1/n) sum{1{Xi <= t} : i=1,...,n}
```

This has to be computed for `t_1<t_2,...,t_m` (e.g. for m different, sorted, values of t). My question is what is the numerical complexity of computing this? I think O(nlog(n))+O(mlog(n)) [sort the array then perform m binary search, one for each value of t]
but I may be naive. Can anyone confirm?

## Edit:

Sorry for the mess. While writing the question, I realized that I was imposing some constraints that are not in the original problem. I respond to Yves's question below.

- The Xi are *not* sorted.
- The t_j *are* sorted **and** *equi-spaced*.
- m is smaller than n, but not by orders of magnitudes: typically m~n/4.

Comment: The function is a bit unclear. Can you explain what you are summing?

Comment: Please be specific: are the Xi's sorted ? are the Tj's sorted ? how is m compared to n ?

Comment: @Yves: It's as it stand now (the 'sorted' that was there before, I realized it's not in the problem specification). The t_j *are* sorted though. Sorry for this. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please answer my three questions.

Comment: Are the `Tj` equally spaced, by any chance ? If yes, an `O(n)` solution is possible.

Comment: Yes! they are! I didn't even think that would play a role. If the O(n) is possible, that would be impressive!

Comment: Yes it is possible; you can rescale all values so that the `Tj`'s become the integers `0..m-1`, and use a histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given expression, a sum of `N` 0/1 terms, is clearly `O(N)`.

UPDATE:
If the `Xi` are presorted, the function is trivially `CDFi = CDF(Xi) = i/N`, and the computation is in a way `O(0)`!

If the `Xi` are unsorted, you'll need to sort first in `O(N.Log(N))`, unless the range of the variable allows a faster sorting such as Counting sort.

If you only need to evaluate for a small number of `Xi`s, let `K`, then you can consider using the naïve summation, as `K.N` can beat `N.Log(N)`.

UPDATE: (second change by the OP)

Else, sort the `Xi` if necessary and sort the `tj` if necessary. Then a single linear pass will suffice. Total complexity will be one of:

```
O(n.Log(n) + m.Log(m))
O(n.Log(n) + m)
O(n + m.Log(m))
O(n + m).
```

If `m < Log(n)` and the `Xi` are unsorted, use the naïve formula. Complexity `O(m.n)`.

Possibly there could be better options when `m>n`.

UPDATE: final specs: `Xi` unsorted, `Tj` sorted, `m < n`.

The solution I would choose is as follows:

1) Sort the `Xi`.

2) "Merge" the sorted `Xi` and `Tj`. This means, progress simultaneously in the `X` and `T` lists, keeping two running indexes; make sure to always increment the index that causes the shortest move; use `CDF(Tj)=i/n`. This is a linear process. (Very close to a merge in mergesort.)

Global complexity is `O(n.Log(n))`, the merging term `O(n)` being absorbed in the former.

UPDATE: uniform sampling.

When the `Tj` values are equi-spaced, let `Tj = T0 + D.j`, you can use an histogram approach.

Allocate an array of `m+1` counters, initially `0`. For every `Xi`, compute a bin index as `Floor((Xi - T0) / D)`. Clamp negative values to `0` and values larger than `m` to `m`. Increment that bin. In the end, every bin will tell you how many `X` values are in range `[Tj, Tj+1[`.

Compute the prefix sum of the counters. They will now tell you how many `X` values are smaller than `Xj+1`, and `CDF(j)=Counter[j]/n`.

[Caution, this is an unchecked sketch, can be wrong in details.]

Total computation will take `n` bin incrementations followed by a prefix sum on `m` elements, i.e. `O(n)` operations.

```
# Input data
X= [0.125, 6, 3.25, 9, 1.4375, 6, 3.125, 7]
n= len(X)

# Sampling points (1 to 6)
T0= 1
DT= 1
m= 6

# Initialize the counters: O(m)
C= [0] * m

# Accumulate the histogram: O(n)
for x in X:
    i= max(0, int((x - T0) / DT))
    if i < m:
        C[i]+= 1

# Compute the prefix sum: O(m)
S= 0
for i in range(m - 1):
    C[i + 1]+= C[i]

# Reduce: O(m)
for i in range(m):
    C[i]/= float(n)

# Display
print "T=", C
```

> > > T= [0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75]

Comment: yea, but you have to evaluate it for every value of t (it's in the definition of the ecdf, but I see I left it out of my question) so doing it naively as you suggest is O(n**2)

Comment: This is exactly why I said "the given expression". There is a single `t` there, so it's `O(N)`. Be specific about the value(s) of `t`.

Answer (score 2):

A CDF Fn(t) is *always* a non-decreasing function in [0..1].  Therefore I assume your notation is saying to count the number of elements Xi <= t and return that count divided by n.

Thus if t is very large, you have n/n = 1.  For very small, it's 0/n = 0 as we'd expect.

This is a poor definition of an empiracle CDF.  See for example see Law, Averill M., *Simulation & Modeling, 4th ed.*, p 301 for some more advanced ideas.

The simplest efficient way to compute your function (given that m, the number of Fn(t) values you need, is unknown) is first to sort the inputs Xi. This requires O(n log n) time, but needs to be done only once no matter how many t values you're processing.

Let's call the sorted values Yi.  To find the count of Yi values <= t is the same as finding i such that Yi <= t < Yi+i.  This can be done by binary search in O(log n) time for a given value of t. Divide by n and you have the Fn(t) value required. Of course you can repeat this m times to get the job done in O(m log n) time.

However you say your special case is m presorted values of t_j.  You can find all the i values with a single pass over the Yi and simultaneously over the t_j, in the fashion of the merge operation in mergesort.  With this you find all the answers in O(m + n) time.

Putting this together with the sorting cost, you have O(m + n + n log n) = O(m + n log n).

Note this is always faster than using the binary search lookup m times, O(n log n + m log n) = O((m + n) log n).

The only case you'd want to skip the presorting is when m < O(log n).  This is because with no presorting, processing all the t_j needs O(mn) time - you must touch all n elements to count the number <= t_j. Consequently, if m < O(log n), then skipping the presort leads to less than O(n log n), i.e. asymptotically faster than the presort method.